# Split filenames into list of lists

Tags: r

I have a bunch of csv file names that I need to read into R and split into a list of lists based on the file name. Say my files are named:

```
"gam_1-1.csv"
"gam_1-2.csv"
"gam_2-1.csv"
"gam_2-2.csv"
```

How do I separate them so that I have a list of lists with the file names, where:

```
list1 <- list("gam_1-1.csv","gam_1-2.csv")
list2 <- list("gam_2-1.csv","gam_2-2.csv")
final_list <- list(list1,list2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split` on a substring of the filenames.

```r
files <- c("gam_1-1.csv", "gam_1-2.csv", "gam_2-1.csv", "gam_2-2.csv")
split(files, sub("-.*", "", files))
# $gam_1
# [1] "gam_1-1.csv" "gam_1-2.csv"
# $gam_2
# [1] "gam_2-1.csv" "gam_2-2.csv"
```